# Clang and GCC accept questionable sizeof

Tags: c++, c++11

I have compilers that disagree on sizeof.  For the following code, Clang and GCC will compile it, but other compilers that I have to use fail claiming "illegal sizeof operand".  My reading of the standard says this is illegal, since `sizeof` can only take an expression (I don't think that S::a is an expression) or a type-id, but it is unusual for GCC and Clang to both be wrong.  I can obviously replace it with `sizeof(S().a)`, which works with all my compilers.

```
struct S
{
   int a[32];
   int b;
   int c;
   int d[32];
};

int main()
{
   return sizeof(S::a);
}
```

Are Clang and GCC wrong, or am I misreading the standard?

Comment: VS2015 also accepts it :) Can you also please specify the "other compilers" and the corresponding gcc/clang versions?

Comment: [This was added in C++11](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2253.html)

Comment: Unable to reproduce - g++ 5.2.1, clang++ 3.6.2.1 on Ubuntu 15.10

Answer (score 26, accepted):

§ 5.1.1 [expr.prim.general] 13

> An id-expression that denotes a non-static data member or non-static member function of a class can only be used:
>
> — as part of a class member access (5.2.5) in which the object expression refers to the member’s class[63] or a class derived from that class, or
>
> — to form a pointer to member (5.3.1), or
>
> — if that id-expression denotes a non-static data member and it appears in an unevaluated operand
>   *[Example:*
>
> ```
> struct S {
>     int m;
> };
>
> int i = sizeof(S::m);      // OK
> int j = sizeof(S::m + 42); // OK
> ```
>
> *-end example]*

Edit:
As @Praetorian points out in comments to the question itself: This was introduced in [C++11](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2253.html)